# Having problems removing a PHP array element

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, foreach

I have an API which returns a multi-dimensional array.

I want to loop over specific parts of the array and output the results into a table.
But there is one item in the first array which I want to omit ["ExtraInformation"] but can't seem to find a way of doing this, even when using the unset() function.

Can someone help with this?

The full array looks like this

```
array(4) {
  ["BillingAccount"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["AccountType"]=>
    string(5) "Trial"
    ["AccountBalance"]=>
    float(999.99)
    ["TransactionCost"]=>
    float(999.99)
    ["ExtraInformation"]=>
    array(0) {
    }
  }
["TechnicalSupport"]=>
  array(7) {
    ["ServerId"]=>
    string(3) "UK1"
    ["RequestId"]=>
    string(32) "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx"
    ["QueryDurationMs"]=>
    int(143)
    ["SupportDate"]=>
    string(10) "19/02/2022"
    ["SupportTime"]=>
    string(8) "20:03:30"
    ["SupportCode"]=>
    string(8) "d4a3a876"
    ["SupportInformationList"]=>
    array(1) {
      [0]=>
      string(6) "B2B-R1"
    }
  }
["Response"]=>
  array(4) {
    ["StatusCode"]=>
    string(7) "Success"
    ["StatusMessage"]=>
    string(7) "Success"
    ["StatusInformation"]=>
    array(1) {
      ["Lookup"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["StatusCode"]=>
        string(7) "Success"
        ["StatusMessage"]=>
        string(7) "Success"
        ["AdviceTextList"]=>
        array(0) {
        }
      }
    }
    ["DataItems"]=>
    array(2) {
      ["VehicleDetails"]=>
      array(3) {
        ["Make"]=>
        string(10) "VOLKSWAGEN"
        ["Model"]=>
        string(22) "TRANSPORTER SE TDI S-A"
        ["BuildYear"]=>
        string(4) "2020"
      }
```

Here are my loops:

```
$details_key = [];
$details_value = [];
foreach($new['Response']['DataItems']["VehicleDetails"] as $key => $value) {
    
    $details_key[] = $key;
    $details_value[] = $value;
    
}
foreach($new["BillingAccount"] as $key => $value) {
    
    $details_key[] = $key;
    $details_value[] = $value;
}
```

Here is my table

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($details_key as $d): ?>
        <th><?= $d ?></th>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <?php foreach($details_value as $v): ?>
        <td><?= $v ?></td>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </tr>
</table>
```

This is what the output looks like but I need to remove the ExtraInformation column

[Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gSXfn.png)

Comment: You mentioned it not working with the unset function, but you didn't provide code for this. Maybe include this next time so we can get a better understanding of what you tried yourself to maybe point out errors in your thinking or misunderstandings.

Answer (score 0):

You are creating a new array, why not check for the key and exclude it?

```
foreach($new["BillingAccount"] as $key => $value) {
    if ($key == "ExtraInformation") continue;
    $details_key[] = $key;
    $details_value[] = $value;
}
```

This would jump this iteration of the loop when the if-statement is true, going to the next element in BillingAccount (if there is any). So Extrainformation is not in the $details_... arrays.